# How can TypeScript support This type of Generic Type?

Tags: typescript

> seems there are already a github issue for this [ts#1213](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213).

This type usage is more like high-order function.
I'm not sure whether TS support it.

The interface is same, but want to implement sync & async version.

```js
interface IO<T> {
  get: () => T<number>;
  set: (v: number) => T<boolean>;
}

type Raw<T> = T;

class SyncO implements IO<Raw> {
  get() {
    return 1;
  }

  set(v) {
    v;
    return true;
  }
}

class AsyncO implements IO<Promise> {
  get() {
    return Promise.resolve(1);
  }

  set(v) {
    v;
    return Promise.resolve(true);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just find an answer when I read [RESTyped](https://github.com/rawrmaan/restyped)'s code:

```js
type MaybePromise<T, P extends boolean> =
  P extends true ? Promise<T> : T;

interface IO<P extends boolean> {
  get: () => MaybePromise<number, P>;
  set: (v: number) => MaybePromise<boolean, P>;

  invalidSet: (v: number) => MaybePromise<boolean, P>;
}

class SyncO implements IO<false> {
  get() { return 1; }
  set(v) { return true; }

/* ts error:
(method) SyncO.invalidSet(v: any): Promise<boolean>
Property 'invalidSet' in type 'SyncO' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'IO<false>'.
  Type '(v: any) => Promise<boolean>' is not assignable to type '(v: number) => boolean'.
    Type 'Promise<boolean>' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.ts(2416)
*/
  invalidSet(v) { return Promise.resolve(true); }
}

class AsyncO implements IO<true> {
  get() { return Promise.resolve(1); }
  set(v) { return Promise.resolve(true); }

/* ts error:
(method) AsyncO.invalidSet(v: any): boolean
Property 'invalidSet' in type 'AsyncO' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'IO<true>'.
  Type '(v: any) => boolean' is not assignable to type '(v: number) => Promise<boolean>'.
    Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'Promise<boolean>'.ts(2416)
*/
  invalidSet(v) { return true; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not fully sure why you have a T that is not generic but then used in your interface as it is. That is a syntax error.

But if you want a merged interface for both you can use the union types with `|`

```
type syncOrAsync<T> = T | Promise<T>; 

interface IO<T> {
  get: () => syncOrAsync<T>;
  set: (v: number) => syncOrAsync<boolean>;
}

class SyncO implements IO<syncOrAsync<number>> {
  get() {
    return 1;
  }

  set(v: number) {
    return true;
  }
}

class AsyncO implements IO<syncOrAsync<number>> {
  get() {
    return Promise.resolve(1);
  }

  set(v: number) {
    return Promise.resolve(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, this code can run, but it can not help validate method return types.
I just find a working way and post it as an answer.

Comment: then why not just make 2 separate interfaces, one for sync and one for async